# Replacing product expressions - named vs. unnamed pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, built-in-symbols

Suppose I have an expression of the form

```
a b c d + x y z
```

The `FullForm` of this is

```
Plus[Times[a,b,c,d], Times[x,y,z]]
```

Now suppose I want to set all expressions containing the product b*c to zero. The naive way of doing this is

```
a b c d + x y z /. Times[___, b, c, ___] -> 0
```

However, this doesn't work - nothing is replaced.

(Background info: I'm expanding some term using `Series`, and would like to cancel out all products dx*dy, so that only first-order terms remain.)

Even more confusing: if I don't use `Times` but a generic function `f` it works - even when I assign all the attributes of `Times` to `f`!

```
f;
SetAttributes[f, #]& /@ Attributes[Times];
Attributes[f]
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[___, b, c, ___] -> 0

==>
{Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}
0
```

(If you evaluate this use a new kernel, as `f` will be `Protected`.)

So: how do I replace expressions containing some product*?

*: Assuming the order of the arguments is known. Don't worry about the fact that the expression for b might be on the left of the one for a; solving this would be another question.

Comment: Feel free to roll back the question title...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, here is the why: patterns do evaluate, just like other expressions. Therefore:

```
Times[___, b, c, ___]
```

gives

```
(*  b c ___^2  *)
```

even before the pattern-matching  is attempted. In this form, the pattern of course does not match. Use `HoldPattern` to prevent that:

```
a b c d+x y z/.HoldPattern[Times[___,b,c,___]]->0

(* x y z *)
```

Comment: @YvesKlett Yes, because the two named underscores are syntactically different. So, the pattern *does* evaluate, but no non-trivial transformation (like raising to a power) can be applied,thus it remains valid for the replacement.

Comment: just saw the ___^2 part and deleted the comment - reading helps!

Answer (score 2):

Is this ok ?

```
expr = a b c d + x y z;
Replace[expr, Times[before___, b, c, after___] -> zero, Infinity] 
(* x y z + zero *)
```

The main point is that the rest of the factors should be named; this works too :

```
a b c d + x y z /. Times[before___, b, c, after___] -> 0
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* the named pattern works?

Comment: No, never had this issue, I always put names. I hope the experts will have an explanation.